# Safely initialize arrays in C in a generic way

Tags: c, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, memset

I wrote some code that uses *memset* to initialize arrays of built-in types like ints, shorts, floats and, more importantly, *pointers*, like

```
typedef void* slot_t;
#define EMPTY_SLOT (slot_t)NULL
...
int n = 10;
slot_t slots[] = (slot_t[])malloc(sizeof(slot_t)*n)
memset(slots,(int)EMPTY_SLOT,n*sizeof(slot_t));
```

this code works nicely in Linux32 where `memset` accepts 32-bit `int`s as second argument (i.e. initializing element), but it's not so for Linux64, where `sizeof(slot_t)>sizeof(int)`, and, IIRC, in other platforms where `memset` accepts `char` as its  second argument. I have yet to verify that any of the bugs I'm experiencing in my project is due to this but, anyway, to be sure, it would be better to adopt a safer, but still "generic", method, if exists. Do you know any?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
slot_t slots[] = (slot_t[])calloc(n,sizeof(slot_t))
```

it's clean memory by itself

Comment: `calloc` fills the returned block with 0, so if that's what's needed - that should be enough.

Comment: Don't cast the return value from `malloc()`.  It can hide bugs and doesn't provide you any value unless you plan to port to C++.

Comment: That doesn't actually compile (neither does the original line with malloc).

Comment: Yeah, the OP needs a `*` and so does this answer.

Comment: @Carl: I didn't think you could initialise an array with a pointer. Clang says: "error: array initializer must be an initializer list".

Comment: @omrib - I meant the type needed to be a pointer, actually.  You're right that you can't initialize an array with a function call like this.

Comment: @Carl: Yes, I see what you mean. But in any case I wouldn't use `calloc` to initialise arrays of pointers, floats, etc.

Comment: @Carl: When I needed speed I've used a loop to initialise the first n cells, then memcpy repeatedly to fill powers of 2, then one last memcpy to fill the end. Portable and usually faster than a C loop.

Comment: @omrib - have you compared it with calloc? Zeroing there can be optimized by compiler (I suspect that it's translated into rep stos.. instruction in most cases). And I highly doubt that multiple calls to memcpy can be faster

Comment: @elevener: I've used this technique when initialising large arrays with non-zero multibyte values. As mentioned in other answers, you shouldn't count on NULL being all-bits-zero if you want to stay portable.

Comment: @omrib You talked about speed. I agree that this code is not portable to computers with non 0 NULL pointers, but I believe that nowadays it hard to find such, and looking at this source code provided it's obvious it's not an issue in this case.

Comment: @elevener: I agree that for short arrays speed doesn't matter, but then for short arrays I'd use a loop (because speed doesn't matter). In any case, the code in the question has more serious issues than speed - it doesn't compile.

Comment: @omrib Don't know what compiler user881430 utilizes - but if his source snipper compiles - this code would compile too. Otherwise you'll simple have to change it to
slot_t *slots = (slot_t *) calloc ( n,sizeof(slot_t) );
And what concerns speed - I belive that for normal compiler for array of any size calloc works faster than your method.

Answer (score 1):

`memset` really wants a *character* as the value to fill the memory with -- note that it fills *bytewise*. So just say `0`. You can put that in your `EMPTY_SLOT` macro if you want. Alternatively, use `calloc()`.

(Also, the return type of your `malloc()` call should be `slot_t *`.)

Comment: `calloc()` has the same issue as `memset()`: it sets the target to all-bits-zero, but the language doesn't guarantee that that's the representation for a null pointer.  And the best idiom for the malloc call is `slot_t *slots = malloc(n * sizeof *slots)`.  (Of course you should immediately verify that `slots != NULL`.)

Comment: @Keith: If you want value-wise filling, you need to iterate over the array and assign values -- I don't think there's any arbitrary-sized flood-fill primitive.

Answer (score 1):

`memset` fills memory with bytes. See [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset).

If you want a *generic* solution - you should write a loop that would iterate and fill. If you're filling with 0, then it doesn't matter what type of data it is and what size it has - just fill 0 with `siezof` of the whole array (`sizeof(slot_t)*n`). Since you're using `NULL`, which doesn't have to be 0 (although usually is) - I suggest taking the safer "loop" approach.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `memset()` is of type int, but it specifies a value to be stored in each *byte* of the destination -- which means that, if `sizeof(int) == 4`, you're zeroing four times as much memory as you should be.

The way to zero-fill the `slots` array would be

```
memset(slots, 0, n * sizeof *slots);
```

(assuming `slots` is correctly declared as a pointer rather than as an array), except that a null pointer representation isn't guaranteed to be all-bits-zero (it probably is, but you shouldn't depend on it).

If you want complete portability, you'll need to write a loop to set each element to NULL.

If you're willing to assume that null pointers are all-bits-zero, you can use `memset` -- but be sure to call it as I specified.

Comment: `slots` is dynamically allocated, running `sizeof` on it will yield a size of a pointer.

Comment: @littleadv: Fixed (though the original code attempted to declare slots as an array, which threw me off).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a completely generic function that will set an array of objects to the values specified by some 'template' object, you could use a function like the following:

```
void init_array( void* arr, size_t nmemb, size_t size, void const* initializer)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    char* p = (char *) arr;

    for (i = 0; i < nmemb; ++i) {
        memcpy( p, initializer, size);
        p += size;
    }
}
```

Then your allocation/initialization code might look like:

```
typedef void* slot_t;

static const slot_t empty_slot = NULL;    // or make this a global if that 
                                          //  works better for your scenario

int n = 10;

// note: your original `malloc()` line:
//
//      slot_t slots[] = (slot_t[])malloc(sizeof(slot_t)*n)
//
// wouldn't work, as you can't assign to an array as a whole.
// That line shouldn't even compile.

slot_t* slots = (slot_t*)malloc(sizeof(slot_t)*n);

// completely generic initialization
init_array( slots, n, sizeof(slot_t), &empty_slot);
```

If you want to initialize an array of pointers, you could have another function that handled that case a little more directly:

```
void init_ptr_array( void* arr, size_t nmemb, void* initializer)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    void* p;

    for (; p < arr + nmemb; ++p) {
        *p = initializer;
    }
}

// arrays of object pointers
init_ptr_array( slots, n, empty_slot);
```

I'm not sure I like that the two functions have a subtly different meaning for last parameter. If I had a need for both kinds of initialization in my program, I'd probably stick with using the generic one for initializing pointer arrays as well.  It might be a bit less efficient, but initialization isn't usually a bottleneck.